# Variation of paramters in DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this equatiom using variation or parameter

$x^2y''-xy'+y=4x+3\ln x$

By making the change of variables $x=e^t$

I understand plugging in the variable and dividing by $e^{2t}$

But how do I get 2 linear independent solutions or a $y_c$ so I can set up a wronskian and then determine $y_p$ then add it to $y_c$ to solve for $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the substitution $x=e^t$ results in an auxiliary equation

\begin{equation}
m(m-1)-m+1=0
\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}
m^2-2m+1=0
\end{equation}

So in terms of $t$ the equation becomes

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-2\dfrac{dy}{dt}+y=4e^t+3t
\end{equation}

Since the solution to the auxiliary equation is $m=1,1$ the solution to the homogeneous equation is

\begin{equation}
y_c=c_1e^t+c_2te^t
\end{equation}

So the two linearly independent functions you need for the Wronskian are $y_1(t)=e^t$ and $y_2(t)=te^t$.

From there you should be able to find the variable parameters $u_1,u_2$ satisfying

\begin{equation}
y_p=u_1e^t+u_2te^t
\end{equation}

which satisfies the non-homogeneous equation.

Comment: Okay so I solve for yp then add that to the yc we have found?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, $y=y_c+y_p$ expressed in terms of $x$ rather than in terms of $t$. $e^t=x,t=\ln(x)$

Comment: Awesome thanks again

Comment: When yoy divide by x^2 on the right side shouldn't it be 4/e^t not 4e^t?

Comment: You would not divide by $x^2$ unless you intended to solve the equation by reduction of order. When you work it using the substitution $x=e^t$ you transform the equation into an equation with variables $y$ and $t$ with a constant leading coefficient (in this case, 1) so there is no need to divide by $x^2$.  You work it as you would any 'constant coefficients' equation remembering to change back to $y$ and $x$. For this particular case, $y_p$ is rather nasty and you have to use integration by parts a couple of times unfortunately.

Comment: Okay so when I find yp I don't have to sub back in x or anything?

Comment: After finding $y=y_c+y_p$ in terms of $t$ you MUST substitute each $e^t$ with $x$ and each $t$ with $\ln(x)$.